# How to convert String into list of Integers in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have the following list of strings in Scala and I wanna convert it into a `List(List(Int))` :

```
val listOfLines = ( "1  2   3   6   9",
                    "1  2   4   5   6",
                    "1  2   8   8   4",
                    "2  3   6   5   4",
                    "2  4   3   9   7" )
```

and I want to convert it to be like :

```
              ( (1,2,3,6,9),
                (1,2,4,5,6),
                (1,2,8,8,4),
                (2,3,6,5,4),
                (2,4,3,9,7))
```

How can I do such thing .. I tried:

`val list = listOfLines.foreach(_.map{(_.split("\t"))}.toList)`

but it gives me error .. any suggestions ?

Comment: Your example `listOfLines` is a Tuple, perhaps you meant to have the word `List` before the parenthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to split on any whitespace you could also do this:

```
listOfLines.map(_.split("\\s+").map(_.toInt).toList)
```

That way you don't have to rely on there only being `\t` characters in there.

This assumes that your input is

```
val listOfLines = List( "1  2   3   6   9",
  "1  2   4   5   6",
  "1  2   8   8   4",
  "2  3   6   5   4",
  "2  4   3   9   7" )
```

As opposed to the tuple in your question

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the answer can be :)

```
val list = listOfLines.map(_.split("\t").toList.map(_.toInt))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Tuple` at the first you need to convert it to `List`:
`listOfLines.productIterator.toList` and you'll obtain `List[Any]`, cause `Tuple` can consist of different type that's why `productIterator` returns `Iterator[Any]`.
And now you can `map` it, but not `foreach`, cause `foreach` returns `Unit`.
So, result is:

```
val res = listOfLines.productIterator.toList
  .map{ 
    _.toString.split("\\s+")
     .map(_.toInt)
     .toList
  }
```